# How to ignore certain characters when sorting table columns

Tags: java, sorting, selenium

I currently have a table that I'm trying to verify the ascending/descending sort using selenium webdriver and java, but I have text that is ignored in the actual sorting and I can't figure out how to ignore the same text to verify the sorting is correct.
This is my current code which gets all the column data

```
protected List<String> getMessageList(Integer column) {
    List<WebElement> messageElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-hover message-grid table table-condensed']/tbody/tr/td[" + column + "]"));
    List<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement element : messageElements) {
        if (!element.getText().equals("")) {
          messageList.add(element.getText());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(messageList);
    return messageList;
}

protected void validateAscendingOrder(Integer column) { List messageList = getMessageList(column);
// create a new list and sort
List<String> sortedmessageList = new ArrayList<String>();
sortedmessageList.addAll(messageList);
Collections.sort(sortedmessageList);

// compare the original list order with the sorted list to make sure they match
assertEquals(sortedmessageList, messageList);
```

}

Here is an example of what my data could look like. Out of Office: Message, Read: Test Message,
Test Message, FW: Another Message, Sample Message
I want to remove the data before the semi-colon (:) because it's not factored into the search.

Answer (score 1):

Create a comparator for your sort like so :

```
Collections.sort(sortedmessageList, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String t, String t1) {
            // do your custom comparator here, for example :
            return t.split(":")[1].compareTo(t1.split(":")[1]);
        }
    });
```

see [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a small code change using java string manipulation shall serve your purpose :

```
if (!element.getText().equals("")) {
  String modifiedString = element.getText().replaceAll(".*:",""); //something greedy learnt
  messageList.add(modifiedString);
}
```

and rest all shall work appropriately using the same logic as present.

***Note*** : Your modified string could also use

```
String modifiedString = element.getText().substring(element.getText().indexOf(":") + 1);
```